# Spotfire - mark records and send to clipboard

Tags: clipboard, ironpython, spotfire

I'd like to create a Spotfire button action control that does the following

1. Select all rows in a table visualization
2. Send the selected rows to the clipboard

First step was handled pretty easily (borrowed from [here](http://spotfired.blogspot.co.id/2014/02/mark-selected-row.html)). For the second step, I was unsuccessful in my initial attempts to send to clipboard with script (e.g. as suggested [here](http://spotfired.blogspot.co.id/2014/03/export-to-excel-pdf-clipboard-etc.html)). I was partially successful in a followup attempt by sending ctrl-c programatically to spotfire (see spotfired.blogspot.co.id/2014/04/pressing-keys-programatically.html).

Here's the [mostly] functioning code:

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import VisualContent
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import IndexSet
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import RowSelection

#Get table reference
vc = vis.As[VisualContent]()
dataTable = vc.Data.DataTableReference

#Set marking
marking=vc.Data.MarkingReference

#Setup rows to select from rows to include
rowCount=dataTable.RowCount
rowsToSelect = IndexSet(rowCount, True)

#Set marking
marking.SetSelection(RowSelection(rowsToSelect), dataTable)

#Script to send keystroke to Spotfire
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
from System.Windows.Forms import SendKeys, Control, Keys

#Send keystroke for CTRL-C Copy-to-clipboard 
SendKeys.Send("^c") #Ctrl+C
```

The code works as expected, except that I have to *hit the button twice* for the ctrl-c part of the script to work (i.e. hitting once results in marking all rows in the table visualization).

Another issue that I seemed to have resolved is that the originally suggested syntax to send the ctrl-c keystroke command was **SendKeys.Send("(^+C)")**. However, this didn't work, so I rewrote as **SendKeys.Send("^c")**, which does work, except only after I hit the button twice.

Any thoughts on how I could fix the issue of having hit the action control button twice?
A workaround could be to avoid sending keystrokes with script and revisit my first attempt code the copy-to-clipboard functionality, but my Ironpython skills are a limiting factor here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same post as reference I used this code to use the windows clipboard

```
tempFolder = Path.GetTempPath()
tempFilename = Path.GetTempFileName()
tp = mytable.As[TablePlot]()
writer = StreamWriter(tempFilename)
tp.ExportText(writer)

f = open(tempFilename)
html=""
for line in f:
   html += "\t".join(line.split("\t")).strip()
   html += "\n"
f.close()


import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')
from System.Windows.Forms import Clipboard
Clipboard.SetText(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, sayTibco, code working for me, now. See below for updated version. Still curious to know how to better utilize SendKeys.Send(), but will make that the subject of a separate post after I have some time to experiment.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import VisualContent, TablePlot
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import IndexSet
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import RowSelection

#get table reference
vc = mytable.As[VisualContent]()
dataTable = vc.Data.DataTableReference

#set marking
marking=vc.Data.MarkingReference

#setup rows to select from rows to include
rowCount=dataTable.RowCount
rowsToSelect = IndexSet(rowCount, True)

#Set marking
marking.SetSelection(RowSelection(rowsToSelect), dataTable)

#Copy marked records to Clipboard
import clr
import sys
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
import System
from System.IO import Path, StreamWriter
from System.Text import StringBuilder

#Temp file for storing the table data
tempFolder = Path.GetTempPath()
tempFilename = Path.GetTempFileName()

#Export TablePlot data to the temp file
tp = mytable.As[TablePlot]()
writer = StreamWriter(tempFilename)
tp.ExportText(writer)
f = open(tempFilename)

#Format table
html=""
for line in f:
   html += "\t".join(line.split("\t")).strip()
   html += "\n"
f.close()

#Paste to system Clipboard
clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')
from System.Windows.Forms import Clipboard
Clipboard.SetText(html)
```