# Create a copy button in Spotfire to copy visual content

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I have a table called Store info. My Spotfire visual will show the URL link for the perticular store. i need to creat a copy button in the same page so that URL displayed has to be copied to clipboard. 
Can some one help out for creating this.

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104978/spotfire-mark-records-and-send-to-clipboard

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that the URL that you want to copy is stored in a document property (named `URL` in my example).

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Windows.Forms')
from System.Windows.Forms import Clipboard
import io

Clipboard.SetText(Document.Properties["URL"])
```